# How to store GIFs for a Github README?

Tags: github, url, gif, readme

I try to include a GIF for my `README.md` in Github, since Github allows to use and render GIFs in `.md` files.

As far as I am concerned I often cannot find any image or video files on Repositories of well maintained Github Repositories, but they still can use their own files in their READMEs.

A few examples:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/i/master/fzf.png 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/master/runtime/vimlogo.gif

How can I achieve **similar links**, without tracking and pushing e.g. GIFs in my Repo on Github?

---

I tried out the following:

1. I open an issue in my Repo, drag and drop my `.gif` file into it, copied the content into my `README.md`.

This turns out successfully, but i receive an not readable link:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/21893471/47281234-9f9b23ff-21ff-88ad-98f1-5555d1239ba807.gif 
(dummy link)

2. I followed this [description](https://gist.github.com/joncardasis/e6494afd538a400722545163eb2e1fa5). It also works, but then an extra branch is created and thus the GIFs will be downloaded as well when someone clones the Repository.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; You can't.

Those "readable" links are links directly into content stored in that repository.  For example, that Vim image lives in this directory in the code: https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/runtime, and will be downloaded by anyone who clones the repository.